# Unable to login after renaming user folder in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, user-profiles

I renamed my folder under `Users` in *Computer Management* from "denni" to "Dennis". I then opened an Administrator Command Prompt and used

```
net user Administrator /active:yes
```

and the command completed successfully. I opened Windows Explorer and I renamed the User folder from "denni" to "Dennis". When I tried to sign out and and sign back in, I get the message that Windows was unable to sign me in and to try to sign out and sign in again.

Every time I try I get the same message.
I don't know what to do now! Please help!

Comment: I was able to rename the folder back to the way it was, but this defeats the purpose. At least I can login again. I would still like to know how to change the folder name without this problem happening again. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You cannot rename the user profile directory using the method you describe.  What you can do is disassociate your account from a Microsoft account, you will be prompted to assign profile name, select the desired name at this time.  After you logout and back into the profile reassign the Microsoft account of you so desire.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have **three** Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/1121539/dennis-harper), [this one](https://superuser.com/users/1121540/dennis-harper), *and* [this one](https://superuser.com/users/1121541/dennis-harper). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: You are going to need to ask a question, provide enough information for me to answer that question if you want anyone to answer that question.  Screenshots of your Settings -> Accounts will be required.

Comment: You have submitted an answer.  Edit your question.  There is absolutely no way for me to answer your question submitted as an answer

Comment: It looks like you have two (or more) accounts. You might want to use the contact us link to get the registered account and unregistered account merged so you can edit your post and comment under them. We're not a forum. and clarifications do not belong in answers